# Windows XP drivers for a Sony VPCEH2A4E

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sony-vaio

This is a long shot but do 32 bit Windows XP drivers exist for a [Sony VPCEH2A4E](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VPCEH2A4E/specifications)?

I'm trying to play a particular game (Fallout 3 if you are interested) that refuses to run under Windows 7 64 bit. I have tried running as Administrator, running in compatability mode etc etc to no avail. Also, it ran like a dog under Windows XP mode so that's out the question.

I have a lot of experience with the Windows XP install process, hard drive partitioning and repairing the Windows 7 boot loader after an XP install onto the same hard drive so no worries there, I am just having trouble finding drivers.

According to Speccy, I have the following hardware:

- Motherboard: Sone VAIO C10743KK Sandy Bridge 09 HM65 B2
- BIOS: INSYDE RO190Z9
- Graphics: Intel HD 9.17.10.2736
- Network: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: *> it ran like a dog under Windows XP mode so that's out the question*   You have obviously not been to the dog-track. `:-P`   Have you tried installing XP yet? If not, do so and see which drivers you actually need since some of them may already be available. Then run Windows Update and [VAIO Update](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/topics/solutions/30070) to see if there are any available there. This way, it will be easier to figure out what exactly is needed (i.e., video? chipset? wireless? audio?)

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I was asking to see if somebody either said yes they are here and the pointed me towards a link, or told me not to waste my time! But I will give it a shot and report back, I feel as though I am about to step into a time machine haha

Comment: Well it depends on the individual components. Thinks like the keyboard, mouse, and NIC may already be supported by Windows, even if only with generic drivers. Things like the video-card, audio card, and even chipset may have drivers available from the [mfgs’](https://www.google.com/search?q=Intel+HD+driver) [sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=ALC889+driver&safe=off) [themselves](https://www.google.com/search?q=HM65+driver&safe=off). That way you can narrow it down to just the proprietary Sony components (if any).

Comment: Just reporting back, the VPCEH2A4E comes with a heavily locked down (and basically useless) BIOS. The Windows XP installer wouldn't reach the `Press Return to Continue` screen (it loaded some drivers and then blue-screened). I had pre-empted the hard drive type being AHCI so had used NLite to slipstream the AHCI driver, but there is clearly other hardware inconpatabilities, and all the BIOS will do let me change the Admin password. Going to try Vista 32 bit and see if it lets me play Fallout 3!

Comment: *> all the BIOS will do let me change the Admin password*   Then do so and log back into the BIOS as an administrator because you may have logged in as a user, which of course does not let you change much. Also, you may need to try entering the BIOS right after powering on as some settings (e.g., changing the hard-drive password, and maybe others) only take effect on power up and are no longer available from simply rebooting.     *> Going to try Vista 32*   Good idea; Vista vastly increased Windows’ hardware support.

Comment: This didn't work, but none the less thankyou for the suggestion. I had literally just looked into the BIOS, and saw that my only option was to set a password and exited. It didn't occur to me that setting a password may give me access to more options. While not the case this time, I will certainly keep this in mind in the future. The same goes with the cold boot, same set of options but something that had never occured to me. From what I can tell, Vista 32 is just a less polished version of 7, nothing really wrong with it, and might just be enough to run my game. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hopefully that will do the trick. Also, try the [BIOS update] if you haven’t already; maybe it gives more control. And you may as well try the help links at the bottom of [the page](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VPCEH2A4E/specifications). Maybe someone in [the forum](http://www.sony.co.uk/discussions/community/en/support/vaio_and_computing) has had a [similar issue](http://genesis.sony-europe.com/instranet/ccil_sony/selfservice/index.jsp?DocId=36760&l=en_GB&m=VAIO) or the [Sony reps](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/modal-box/contact/email-vaio) can tell you what your options are.